# C++ Error: no match to call <class constructor (char*&, char*&, char*&, char*&)

Tags: c++, mysql, class, vector, constructor

What I'm trying to do with this program is I have a MySQL result table, and I am iterating through the rows. Each row has 5 columns and I want to store each field into the private data members of a class. Then once I have that class, I want to push_back the class into a vector of the class type. So in my main.cpp I have:

```
Wine wines("None", 0, 0, 0, "None");
```

Which is supposed to call this constructor:

```
Wine::Wine(string inputName, int inputVintage, int inputRating, int inputScore, string inputType) {
   name = inputName;
   vintage = inputVintage;
   rating = inputRating;
   score = inputScore;
   type = inputType;
}
```

Back in the main:

```
    vector<Wine> wineVector;
    res = mysql_perform_query(conn, (char*)cmd.str().c_str()); //cmd is just a ostringstream holding the query.
    loadResultsToVector(wines, wineVector, res);
```

Where loadResultsToVector is defined as:

```
void loadResultsToVector(Wine w, vector<Wine> wineVec, MYSQL_RES *results) {
 MYSQL_ROW row;
 while((row = mysql_fetch_row(results)) != NULL) {
  w(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]); //Initializes Wine w, error occurs here.
  wineVec.push_back(w);
 }
 mysql_free_result(results); //Clears result table
}
```

So when I try to initialize the class with the information from the row, I get this error:

```
no match to call to '(Wine) (char*&, char*&, char*&, char*&, char*&)'
w(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]); //Initializes Wine w, error occurs here.
                                        ^
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The error message is enough clear. Read the error message. The compiler issues error messages specially for you.

Comment: Either convert the integers to C-Style strings before calling the function or change the parameter types of the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
Wine w,
// ...
w(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]);
```

compiler thinks that you want to call `operator()` on `w` object, or that `w` is a function. I think you want to call a constructor on `Wine` and initialize `w` parameter:

```
w = Wine(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]);
```

But then why make `w` a function parameter. This : `Wine w(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]);` should suffice.

Another problem is that your constructor expects different parameters. Its signature is : `string, int, int, int, string`, not four `char*`. So you need to do conversions.

Comment: Oh that's interesting, but it fixed my problem so thank you! I have also taken into account the type conversions using atoi and atof.